# Opening pickle files and adding to them

Tags: python-2.7, object, pickle

I am trying to store information in a pickle file and then continually append new information to this file without out over-writing any information. The only issue here is that if i close the program and re-run it creating a new object and saving it to the output over-writes the previous information, fairly sure there is a simple solution to this. My code looks something like this:

```
#save object to file function
def save_object(obj, filename):
  with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


#Add employee to dict, increment id
def add_employee(self,employee):
  self.employee_dict[self.employee_id] = employee
  employee.id = self.employee_id
  self.employee_id += 1


#Get object info, call add_employee, save object
employee = Employee.from_input()
self.add_employee(employee)                    
Employee.save_object(self.employee_dict, r'Obj_file.pkl')
```

EDIT: To load the file i am using this:

```
elif self.menu_select == 5:
  self.load_file = open("Obj_file.pkl", 'rb+')
  self.employee_dict = pickle.load(self.load_file)
  print self.employee_dict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use append mode:

```
  with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
```

=>

```
  with open(filename, 'ab') as output:
```

Otherwise it will rewrite the file every time.

Comment: I knew it! haha, I'm reading the documentation but, there is so much in here i guess i just didn't get to that part yet, thank you : )

Comment: surprisingly this isn't working. No errors or anything it just does the same thing.

Comment: I take that back, okay after looking at the .pkl file it is in fact working but when i load the file it just shows the first two in the list for some reason?

Comment: @After_Sunset how do you load? you have to load as many times as many objects have been saved.

Comment: @After_Sunset so you load only once. You have to refactor you code. pickle.load(self.load_file) means that pickle will pop the latest object from the file.

Comment: See the top again i made an edit, yeah i get what your saying but not quite sure how to do it, update() maybe or put the load code in a loop?

Comment: I'd recommend to keep all objects you need in a list. And then save and load entire list from the file. In this case you may use 'wb' mode because you store only one object (the list with objects).

Comment: Okay, i did not know that thank you, also i can't use a list because when i add in a delete function to erase employees i need the keys representing each object to remain the same even if one is deleted.

Comment: then a dictionary your choice ;)